# fluentd not capturing milliseconds for time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, fluentd

I am using fluentd version 0.14.6. I want to have the milliseconds (or better) captured by fluentd and then passed on to ElasticSearch, so that the entries are shown in the correct order. Here is my fluentd.conf:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/app/rails/current/log/development.log
  pos_file /home/app/fluentd/rails.pos
  tag rails.access

  format /^\[(?<time>\S{10}T\S{8}.\d{3})\] \[(?<remoteIP>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\] \[(?<requestUUID>\w+)\] \[AWSELB=(?<awselb>\w+)\] (?<message>.*)/
   time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
 </source>

<match rails.access>
  @type stdout
  time_as_integer false
</match>
```

And here is a sample log entry from Rails

```
[2016-09-27T19:10:05.732] [xxx.xxx.xxx.46] [46171c9870ab2d06bc3a9a0bb02] [AWSELB=97B1C1B51866B68887CF7F5B8C352C45CA31592743CF389F006C541D59ED5E01852E7EF67C807B1CFC8BC145D569BCB9859AFCA73D10A87920CF2269DE5A47D16536B33873DEEF4A24967661232B38E564] Completed 200 OK in 39.8ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 14.9ms)
```

This all parses fine, except the milliseconds are dropped. Here is a result from STDOUT

```
2016-09-27 19:43:56 +0000 rails.access: {"remoteIP":"xxx.xxx.xxx.46","requestUUID":"0238cb3d812534487181b2c54bd20","awselb":"97B1C1B51866B68887CF7F5B8C352C43CA21592743CF389F006C541D59ED5E01852E7EF67C807B1CFC8BC145D569BCB9859AFCA73D10A87920CF2269DE5A47D16536B33873DEEF4A24967661232B38E564","message":""}
```

I have [searched SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluentd%20millisecond%20time), but the two posts listed are from a time before [this PR](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/pull/653), which is supposed to add in milliseconds. It is merged. The PR mentions adding a `time_as_integer` option, which I have done. I tried setting it to both true and false, as there is some confusion in the PR, but it made no difference. I also tried putting it into the source, but that threw an error.

I also looked at [this post](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/679), which is trying to get to nano second, which I don't need. It also is not a good solution for me, as the time would then come from fluentd, not Rails.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Your `source` is properly configured, the milliseconds are available to the output plugin. The `stdout` output plugin does not output milliseconds [code](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/v0.14.6/lib/fluent/plugin/out_stdout.rb#L72).

You can test the milliseconds availability by using the file output plugin.

```
<match rails.access>
  @type file
  path example.out.log
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
</match>
```

The ElasticSearch output plugin takes milliseconds into account [source](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch/tree/v1.7.0#time_key_format).